Java CodeCache is Full executing PlantUML / GraphViz
I am attempting to generate diagrams for my plantuml file locally but keep coming across a Java CodeCache error, I understand in theory what the issue is, that is I need to increase the Cache size, however I do not know how to do this for plantuml / GraphViz specifically and can't seem to find any resource online to show me how.
Within my planuml file I am right clicking and selecting preview current diagram (equally trying to export current diagram raises the same issue). The output is then an exclamation mark with the warning about increasing CodeCache size, which I appreciate it gives me instructions for the command to execute but it has failed when attempting to do so. I have attached a screenshot of the error within.  error
I attempted to increase the CodeCacheSize via java -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=256m in terminal optimistic it would increase the default value for all programs using java, but it did not and simply returned a list of flags that were accepted by java, none of which were -XX.

Can you provide further information. How to you call PlantUML? From command line? Can you paste your command? Can you list the error message?
